# Output strings via grep excluding matches within them

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way, to output strings found with `grep`, excluding matches?

Let's say I have a file with strings:

```
>A.123 TextTextTextText....
>B.123 OtherTextTextText....
```

I would like to get the following:

```
>TextTextTextText...
>OtherTextTextText...
```

I use the following command to search for such strings:

```
grep -P '(?<=>)[A-Z0-9\.]*\s' File.txt
```

It finds matches correctly, but I can't figure out how to output all lines in a separate file, excluding matches within them.

I know that there is a `-o` flag that can be used to get only matches. Is it possible to "invert" it?

Comment: grep has a `-v, --invert-match` option, but that can only be used for selecting lines not matching the pattern

Comment: Why not use `cut`? e.g. `cut -d' ' -f2` or if you just want to remove the start of the line: `sed 's/^>[^ ]* />/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk '/^>/ {print ">" $2}' file
>TextTextTextText...
>OtherTextTextText...
```